# PHP return array key

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have an array $food like:

```
Array
(
    [apple] => Array
        (
            [color] => red
            [type] => fruit
        )

    [choco] => Array
        (
            [color] => brown
            [type] => candy
        )

)
```

Is there a function where I can do:

get_key($food, 0) and it would return index 0, apple

get_key($food, 1) returns choco

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this :

```
$keys = array_keys($array);

echo $keys[0];
echo $keys[1];
```

Answer (score 5):

```
function get_key($array, $index) {
    $allItems = array_keys($array);
    $selectedItem = $allItems[$index];
    return $selectedItem;
}
```